# Newly-earned tag badge shows pop-up for newly-earned normal badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

So, I recently earned a couple of badges - one Proofreader and one tag badge:

[image: screenshot of profile page showing award messages for both badges]

One small problem: clicking the tag badge shows the pop-up for the proofreader badge:

[image: screenshot showing wrong pop-up for tag badge]

Clearly, this is a calculated effort to convince me to edit more and decline less, which is admirable.  But all it has accomplished is distracting me by prompting this bug report, so the noble attempt has failed.

Comment: Master on Meta...

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be fixing these bugs?

Comment: I took this job so that I could selfishly badger other people to fix bugs.

Comment: So what happened when you hovered over the proofreader badge? Were they swapped or was proofreader the popup for both?

Comment: Same popup for both badges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm both shocked and amazed that you found this. It ended up being a kind of hairy situation, we were setting variables in JavaScript that were being read elsewhere and doubled up so only the latest one would work.

I moved stuff around to make it a little bit more stable. It's fixed as of the next build, and instead of making you recreate the conditions to test here's a GIF:

[image: both pop-ups working correctly]

Thanks!

Comment: Verified: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEySZ.gif